# By default, is DispatchQueue .serial or .concurrent?

Tags: cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

That's the question, straight-forward as that.

```
let serial = DispatchQueue(label: "serial", attributes: .serial)
let concurrent = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrent", attributes: .concurrent)
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "q")
```

I see no property I can inspect on `q` that will tell me.

Running in playground with `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` shows serial behavior, but I don't want to rely on playground (kind of janky with async stuff), or undocumented behavior.

Can anyone offer a hard answer with a link to documentation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Prior to Swift 3, the default dispatch queue type was serial – [passing `nil` into the attributes parameter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create) of `dispatch_queue_create` would yield a serial queue, and I see no reason for the default queue type to change. Although unfortunately I can't find any documentation on `DispatchQueue` that can confirm this.

However, [looking at the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/swift/Queue.swift#L183) reveals that this is indeed still the case:

```
public convenience init(
    label: String,
    attributes: DispatchQueueAttributes = .serial, 
    target: DispatchQueue? = nil)
{
    ...
}
```

Although I always prefer to specify the attribute explicitly, to make my code clearer and prevent this kind of confusion.

Comment: The source code link was awesome, thanks. I didn't see the default param implementation when I cmd+clicked on the method name in xcode.

Comment: @SimplGy Happy to help :)

Answer (score 12):

**UPD Swift 5**

The answer by @Hamish holds true: a new DispatchQueue is serial by default.
And though the default value for attributes in the source code does not specify ".serial" anymore as it used to:

```
public convenience init(
        label: String,
        qos: DispatchQoS = .unspecified,
        attributes: Attributes = [],
        autoreleaseFrequency: AutoreleaseFrequency = .inherit,
        target: DispatchQueue? = nil)
```

it is noteworthy that the set of Attribute values has `.concurrent` option but not `.serial` any more.
So again, serial by default, and concurrent if otherwise explicitly assigned in the attributes array.